# Shut down button shortcut on Android TV

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, android-tv, shutdown, power-options

Can we create a shortcut (or install an app) on Android TV launcher - that would immediately shut down (or switch to standby if complete shutdown isn't possible, or open the power menu with shutdown, restart and other options, if that's possible) the device which is running Android TV? Or maybe there are some launchers for Android TV that have such button implemented?

I'm using Homatics Box R 4K Plus box with Android TV 11.